# Multiple docker .env for multiple servers(prod, dev) that containers use?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, docker-stack

I really did not know how to word the title.

In my system I have two instances:

- a Prod server
- a Dev server

Dev used mostly for testing. In each case I have two versions of AMQP both having different hostnames.

To avoid duplication or unnecessary time rewriting the same code in multiple projects I wanted to use the env file that docker compose has, though everywhere I read, no one discusses this case. That case being that depending on where a stack is deployed is which env file it would use and that env file existing on the swarm itself rather than the individual projects.

Hopefully, I didn't miss anything when explaining this. Summary being two swarms each having their own env file that the containers deployed to it can use. Also if I need to reword anything, I will do so.

Comment: Is the whole app containerised (including AMQP)?

Comment: AMQP is in a container of its own, everything would be in their own container, those container can have more than one service

Comment: Can you use compose networks so that dev and prod servers have the same name?

Comment: Well im trying to keep them separated as much as i can so that nothing is crossing over

Comment: If they are running on separate networks they won't be able to cross over

Comment: Im not trying to cross over anything though

Comment: So i have figured a better word what i am looking for. I am looking to be able to use external env files just like how docker secrets and configs work. Where a service can just call upon it and use it.

Answer (score 0):

you can have multiple [.env](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers) files and assign them to services in `docker-compose.yml` like

```
web:
  env_file:
    - web-variables.env

nginx:
  env_file:
    - nginx-variables.env
```

and if you want to change them for development environemnt you could [override](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#example-use-case) the docker-compose.yml with `docker-compose.development.yml`file and then start it with

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.development.yml up -d
```

Comment: Well im more looking for the env files existing on the network so that when a container is being run it takes it from there kind of like a secret or config

Comment: you can create this .env file with your CI - CD deployment, are you using for example gitlab-ci ?

Comment: I am using gitlab-ci

Comment: Si i have figured a better word what i am looking for. I am looking to be able to use external env files just like how docker secrets and configs work. Where a service can just call upon it and use it.